# Algorithm to realize monotone polyline?

Tags: algorithm, line

I'm searching about the algorithm helping me realize monotone polyline.

I would wonder if anyone has any program realizing monotone polyline.

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//02240000000p000000

Answer (score 1):

You do not state which GIS system you intend to implement this within, so assuming ArcGIS and you know a little VBA or .Net then you can easily query the Monotonicity of a polyline using the [IMSegmentation3](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/MMonotonicity_Property/002m00000241000000/) Interface.